# Sending data with HTTP and TcpClient not completely sent

Tags: c#, http, tcpclient

What I'm trying to do is sending data with HTTP protocol with TcpClient. But i faced a problem here. The data i sent (after the headers) was not completely sent to the client's app (eg. browsers). Code:

```
// Building data.
string notfound = "NOT FOUND";
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(notfound);

// Building header.
m_responseBuilder.Append("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found").Append(CRLF);
m_responseBuilder.Append("Server: ETP").Append(CRLF);
m_responseBuilder.Append("Content-Type: text/plain").Append(CRLF);
m_responseBuilder.Append("Content-Length: ").Append(data.Length.ToString()).Append(CRLF);
m_responseBuilder.Append(CRLF);
byte[] header = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m_responseBuilder.ToString());

// Sending header.
await SendDataAsync(header);

// Sending data.
await SendDataAsync(data);
```

The SendDataAsync:

```
async Task SendDataAsync(byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            await m_tcpchannel.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        catch
        {
            DestroyConnection();
        }
    }
```

What I got:

```
NOT FOUN
```

Whats wrong right here?

Comment: 1)  Why not use HttpListener?  and 2) Of course its broken, yer stickin' your finger in the byte soup and stirring it around. (you can't UTF8 encode an image; Encoding is for strings, that's why its in the System.Text namespace).

Comment: 1) I want to learn abt http packets

Comment: 2) the file is not encoded to string, it sent directly as bytes

Comment: SendResponse() do not encode anything. it was sent as bytes

Comment: Ah.  My mistake.

Comment: that's ok... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, i got the problem. It was the CRLF. I wrote it \n\r instead of \r\n....